# Can I add an action to a NSImage which is drawn in a NSTextFieldCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can I add an action to a NSImage which is drawn in a NSTextFieldCell ?

Or should I implement a NSImageView or NSButton for it ? If so, how do I add such view or button to the NSTextFieldCell ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using NSImage,you can use NSButton .Set its image as you are doing for NSImage.Add the selector for that button .

```
   NSButton *objNSButton = [[NSButton alloc] init];
    [objNSButton setImage: YourImage];
   [objNSButton setTarget:self];
   [objNSButton setAction:@selector(buttonAction:)];
   [objNSButton drawWithFrame:'SelfDefinedRectForButton' inView:NStextFieldCellObject];
```

You can also setAlternate image option if you want chagne in image on click of that button.

Comment: warning: 'NSButton' may not respond to '-drawWithFrame:inView:'

Answer (score -1):

create a custom Button with UIButtonTypeCustom and then set image by using -setImage function and then add a selector as a target.

You can also [refer this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)